# bind ng-style from dynamic html

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a problem with some dynamic data that it is stored in database.
I am storing in database div with ng-style, and then when response is back from server with this div , will like to apply a style to this div.

If it is not dynamic, I have no problems.
this is my code:

This my static html.

```
<div ng-controller="empty" >
    <div>
        <div ng-bind-html="validData | unsafe"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is comming from database.

```
<div class="row">   
    <div ng-style="visualization" class="col-md-4">.col-md-2</div>   
    <div ng-style="visualization" class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div> 
</div> 
<div class="row">
    <div ng-style="visualization" class="col-md-4">.col-md-8</div>
</div>
```

and this should be my controller.

```
$http.get(globalVars + 'page/' + lastParam)
  .success(function (data) {
    $scope.empty = data;

    $scope.validData = $scope.empty.layout.schema;

    $compile($scope.validData);

    if(typeof $rootScope.mode == 'undefined' || $rootScope.mode    =='edit'){

       $scope.visualization = {
         "border-style": "dashed"
       }
    }
    else{
       $scope.visualization = {
         "border-style": "none"
    }
  }
  })
  .error(function (data) {
});
```

in theory, in each div from data coming from database should be added `"style=border-style:none/dashed"`,but this not happening, so `ng-style` it is not binded to angular.

some help should be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $compile(html) function returns another function to which you can pass the $scope variable.  You could try doing:

```
$scope.validData = $compile($scope.validData)($scope);
```

This could make your controller code look like:

```
$http.get(globalVars + 'page/' + lastParam).success(function (data) {
  $scope.empty = data;

  $scope.validData = $scope.empty.layout.schema;
  if(typeof $rootScope.mode == 'undefined' || $rootScope.mode    =='edit'){

    $scope.visualization = {
      "border-style": "dashed"
    }
  }else{
    $scope.visualization = {
      "border-style": "none"
    }
  }

  $scope.validData = $compile($scope.validData)($scope);

}).error(function (data) {

});
```

However there are other ways of doing what you're trying to achieve, possibly using CSS.  For example, place a conditional class using ng-class, on the outer div:

```
<div ng-class="{'edit-mode': editModeEnabled }" ng-bind-html="validData | unsafe"/>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.edit-mode .row > div { 
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

And set editModeEnabled in your controller:

```
$scope.editModeEnabled = $rootScope.mode === 'edit';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, it works adding scope to compile, but now I have a problem with untrusted string, It is working properly if I do not add compile, but when I add compile, I get typical error :  **Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html**

Comment: I think adding "style" attribute would make it untrusted.  You could replace this with a class="" and define the CSS in a stylesheet.  Or else you can treat the HTML as trusted but this would be done with great care to ensure you aren't opening yourself to security issues with untrusted user data.

Comment: I think problem comes from compile, because it returns an array instead html.

Comment: You might have to scroll down a bit:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

"Calling the linking function returns the element of the template."

So rather than an array, it's an element that you see returned.  You can get the HTML string from the element.

However, I would recommend using another approach, perhaps the CSS alternative I suggested in the answer.  Because otherwise I think you may still end up with static HTML, which will not update when you change the edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I used your suggestion.

```
div ng-class="{'edit-mode': editModeEnabled }" ng-bind- html="validData | unsafe"/>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.edit-mode .row > div { 
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

regards